# If statement inside array php

Tags: php, arrays, function, codeigniter, if-statement

I am trying to update the database with new `newpwd` only if the new password is entered... Otherwise, i would like it to leave it as it was...

Currently, I am using a workaround and setting it as the `password` field which is the current password on `else`. So my question is, is there a way for me to avoid using an else statement? I don't want to update the `password` row in the database if the new password is not entered.

My code:

```
$this->db->update("userinfo", array(
'email' => $this->input->post('email'), 
'password' => ($this->input->post('newpwd') !== "") ? md5($this->input->post('newpwd')) : md5($this->input->post('password'))));
```

Comment: Eeeep! Don't use MD5 for password hashing!!! http://php.net/password_hash

Comment: Don't use md5 for Passwords use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it to array conditionally, like following code:

```
$userData['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
if ($this->input->post('newpwd') !== "") { 
    $userdata['password'] = md5($this->input->post('newpwd'));
}

$this->db->update("userinfo", $userData);
```

Comment: Don't use md5 for Passwords use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Yes I know but that is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Define array outside of this statement.

`$arr = array(
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'), 
);`

Only push the 'password' key into the array if new password is entered.

`if($this->input->post('newpwd') !== "") {
  $arrName = array_merge($arr, array('Password' => md5($this->input->post('newpwd'))));
}`

Then provide the array to update statement like following statement

`$this->db->update("userinfo", $arrName);`